# amqp appender and log4j2

Tags: amqp, log4j2, appender

I am trying to use amqpappender from spring amqp project in our project
See here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/log4j/AmqpAppender.html

But we are currently using log4j2 which I do not think amqp appender supports.
Does anyone know if amqp appender works with log4j2?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spring AMQP v.1.6.0.M1](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/) (or hight) and [log4j2 xml configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Appender example:

```
<RabbitMQ name="rabbitmq"
      host="localhost" port="5672" user="guest" password="guest" virtualHost="/"
      exchange="log4j2Test" exchangeType="fanout" declareExchange="true" durable="true" autoDelete="false"
      applicationId="testAppId" routingKeyPattern="%X{applicationId}.%c.%p"
      contentType="text/plain" contentEncoding="UTF-8" generateId="true" deliveryMode="NON_PERSISTENT"
      charset="UTF-8"
      senderPoolSize="3" maxSenderRetries="5">
</RabbitMQ>
```

Comment: This seems to be in the correct direction. However log4j2 complains RabbitMQ is not recognizable any leads?

Comment: Could you help me, please, with it? [log4j2.xml and error](https://gist.github.com/xtender/ecd20ed8febefe62bca065c858d92598)   I use 1.6.0.M2, but still get error: `ERROR Appenders contains an invalid element or attribute "RabbitMQ"`

Comment: @raam86 maybe you will help comment from Beni Murza

Comment: @xt.and.r maybe RabbitMQ appender wasn't installed. The package contained not in the main repository.

Answer (score 1):

As @Illiahat pointed out, you have to use the latest (unreleased yet) version, such as `1.6.0.M2`. The current version (`1.5.5`) does not support log4j**2**, that's why you'd get a `RabbitMQ is not recognizable` message (it cannot use the `AppenderSkeleton` class).

Here's a gradle configuration example that will get the logger working:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.5'
    compile 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.6.0.M2'
}
```

For the logger, you can use the configuration from @Illiahat.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me: [configs and logs](https://gist.github.com/xtender/ecd20ed8febefe62bca065c858d92598)

Comment: Interesting, that I see `public class AmqpAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {` in the log4j directory, but log4j**2** contains `public class AmqpAppender extends AbstractAppender {`

Comment: @xt.and.r Maybe try with  <AppenderRef ref="rabbitmq"/> (exactly how the `name` property looks like in your XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Log4j 2, you should be able to go through an AMQP JMS provider.

For example, Apache Qpid JMS is a complete AMQP 1.0 Java Message Service 1.1 client built using Qpid Proton.

Qpid also provides an alternate JMS client supporting earlier AMQP versions.

See https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/